# Fetch Tweet information via ID and display it on linked webpage [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm working on a Node.js project that fetches 5 tweets with a specific tag and displays them on the webpage as a list (JUST the text is displayed). Once they are loaded on the page, I would like each one to link to a seperate page that displays the rest of its information (User, date, etc).

Looking through Twitter's API documentation, I believe I have to use GET statuses/show/:id, but I'm not sure that I'm actually implementing this correctly.

I'm using Node.js, Express.js, and Pug.

In short, I have three questions; How do I go about extracting the Id of each tweet? How do I plug the extracted ID into a link in my Pug template? How do I display the rest of the tweet's information on the linked page via the ID?

Here was my attempt, but as I mentioned, I'm confused on how to use statuses/show/:id

**main.js**

'use strict';

```
const express = require('express'),
    Twitter = require('twitter'),
    request = require('request'),
    app = express(),
    tweets = [];

const T = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token_key: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
});

const params = {
    q: 'cool',
    count: 5
} 

T.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data, response) {
    for(let i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++){ 
        tweets.push(data.statuses[i].text);
    }
});

T.get('statuses/show/:id', function(data, req, res) {
    const statusId = req.params.id;

})

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static('resources'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'text/html');
    res.render('normal', {tweets: tweets});
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

**relevant part of layout.pug**

```
                ul
                    #tweetCSS
                        each tweet in tweets
                            li= tweet //How do I include ID within link here?
```